# How do you control the number of times a functions calls, in a recursive function. I.e the number of times the recursive function calls on itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 functions right now, one of them is to code a simple recursive function that will calculate exponents in n number of steps

the second function which is my primary problem, is n/2 steps. I am confused on how to negotiate or control the number of recursive calls which is represented by n.

this is an assignment question, i am not allowed to use loops of any kind, "while" and "for" are not allowed, only if thens, so please go easy on me because i know it looks simple.

```
def simple_recursive_power(x, n):
    print("n="+str(n))
    if n ==1:
        return x
    else:
        return x* simple_recursive_power(x,n-1)

print("the simple recurse method="+ str(simple_recursive_power(3,3)))

""the above works, the one below is working the wrong way""

def advanced_recursive_power(x, n):
    print("n="+str(n))
    if n <= 1:
        return x

    else:
        return x * advanced_recursive_power(x, n-1/2)


print("advanced recursion="+ str(advanced_recursive_power(3,3)))
```

Comment: `n-1/2` doesn't do what you want it to do. See [operator precedence](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity).

Comment: The better exponential function that takes half of the cycles does not just need an adjustment of N, it needs a better algorithm.

Comment: Your second function is n*2 steps, not n/2 steps.

Comment: i tried that, n-(1/2), inorder to get it right, but it still prints out ridiculous answers past a certain value of n

Comment: `n-(1/2)` is equivalent to `n-1/2`. Read the link.

Comment: @Amadan, when you say better algorithm, i understand that my if statements are wrong, but the thing is the algorithm works to a certain extent. Like for example if i change the return statement in 
```
advanced_recursive(x, n-1.5), it works to a degree, like it cuts down the steps and the calls but after a certain valuation it starts to give wrong answers

Comment: @AshwinSarith: It does cut down the steps, but the algorithm you were using _needs_ that many steps. As I said, with cutting down steps, you need to also change the algorithm (as shown in the answer, below.)

Comment: Are you required to take exactly n/2 steps for the second one, or is it fine to have log2(n) steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better exponential function that takes half of the cycles does not just need an adjustment of N, it needs a better algorithm.

The simple exponent works like this: take N steps, at each step multiply what you have with X.

If you want to halve the number of steps, the crucial detail to notice is that, if you multiply with X*X, you are taking *two steps at a time*.

```
def advanced_recursive_power(x, n):
    print("n="+str(n))
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    else:
        return x * x * advanced_recursive_power(x, n - 2)
```

Now, this cuts down number of function invocations, but not number of multiplications: for example with N = 7, we went from `X * X * X * X * X * X * X` to `X * (X * X) * (X * X) * (X * X)`. If we could just pre-calculate `X * X`, we could actually cut down on multiplications as well... This will calculate `(X2 = X * X); X * X2 * X2 * X2`, with four multiplications, not seven:

```
def super_advanced_recursive_power(x, n):
    print("n="+str(n))
    if n % 2 == 0:
        start = 1
    else:
        start = x
    return start * simple_recursive_power(x * x, n // 2)
```

Comment: so basically in order to halve the steps, I input the first 2 steps and that thereby reduces the number of visible steps?

Answer (score 0):

You can drastically cut down the number of steps if you pass on powers:

```
def arp(x, n):
    """Advanced recursive power equivalent to x ** n"""
    print('#', x, n)
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    elif n % 2:  # odd exponential
        return x * arp(x * x, (n - 1) // 2)
    else:  # even exponential
        return arp(x * x, n // 2)
```

This takes O(log n) steps only.

```
>>> arp(3, 15)
# 3 15
# 9 7
# 81 3
# 6561 1
14348907
```

---

This is the equivalent of expressing addition as a series of decrements and increments:

```
def recursive_add(x, y):
    if y == 0:
       return x
    return (x + 1, y - 1)
```

This uses that `x + y == (x + 1) + (y - 1)`. Similarly, for powers the relation `x ** n == (x * x) ** (n / 2)` holds true. While it is pretty slow for addition (linear) it is fast for powers (exponential).

This exploits that even powers repeat terms. For example, `2**8` can be written as `((2 * 2) * (2 * 2)) * ((2 * 2) * (2 * 2))` - notice how the term `2 * 2` and `(2 * 2) * (2 * 2)` repeats. We can rewrite `2**8` as `((2 ** 2) ** 2) ** 2`. This is exactly what the last term for even exponentials does recursively.

For odd exponentials, we have the problem that we would go from, say, `2 ** 3` to `4 ** 1.5`. Thus, we use `x ** n == x * (x ** (n - 1))` to go from an odd to an even exponent. Since we have excluded the case of `n == 1`, we know that `n >= 3` and thus it is safe to proceed with `x * x, (n-1) // 2` directly.

The net effect is that n is halved on each step, not just once.

Comment: The question requires that i cut down by n/2 steps. But i am curious how you were able to cut down the recursion by so much. And how are you are able to count them as well.

Comment: I have added an explanation on how this works. Hope it helps.